# Управление Objective-C классом из C кода

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Допустим, мне нужна библиотека на C, которая содержит Objective-C классы. Например:

```
const void *createEmptyNSObject()
{
    return (const void *) [NSObject new];
}
```

Будут ли утечки памяти, если использовать `[[NSObject new] autorelease]`?
Есть ли варианты, кроме написания функции, выполняющей `release`?

Answer (score 0):

По тексту вопроса предполагаю, что ARC при компиляции библиотеки вы не используете.

Если не использовать ARC, созданный объект обязан кто-либо удалить. При вызове у объекта `autorelease` освобождать его будет ближайший по области видимости autorelease pool. Если в вашей программе, использующей библиотеку, не создать такой пул вручную, вызов метода autorelease упадёт в рантайме. В вашем случае, я предполагаю, вы хотите абстрагировать весь objc за библиотекой – а это значит, что подход с autorelease pool не сработает, объекты нужно очищать вручную предложенной вами функцией для `release`.

На самом деле куда проще было бы не тянуть за собой objc совсем, если существующий код можно сразу переписать на C, например, через CoreFoundation (если вы пользуетесь Foundation-классами). Там уже решен вопрос с управлением памятью (`CFRetain`/`CFRelease`) и API во многом похож на Foundation (Foundation на Linux, например, полностью внутри использует CoreFoundation и не зависит даже от рантайма objc).

Если же CoreFoundation почему-то не устраивает, или (судя по вашему примеру) вы используя С-библиотеку всё равно работаете с objc, то зачем писать свою обёртку, если уже есть *сам рантайм objc*? (`<objc/runtime.h>`). Сама реализация языка доступна в виде вызовов на C и, возможно, вам этого хватит.

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать `autorelease` - утечек памяти не будет, но объект вскоре после выхода из функции будет удален. Причем работать это будет только совместно с autorelease pool. Суть `autorelease` лишь в том, чтобы упростить управление памятью.

Для того, чтобы объект не умер надо использовать `CFRetain`/`CFRelease`, как советует Дмитрий.

Учтите также, что `strong` переменные работать с указателем типа `void *` не будут - компилятор не поймет.